# How to force Nextjs to create a chunk for particular module?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, import, next.js, dynamic-import

I'm trying to use dynamic import for importing a different modules depending on the props passed to the component. Paths to the components are kept in an object

```
const components = {
    'apple': './Apple.js',
    'orange': './Orange.js',
    // ...
}
```

Then

```
// ...
import(components[this.props.type])
// ...
```

Unfortunately, I get the following error:

`Unhandled Rejection (Error): Cannot find module './Apple.js'`

It disappears when I explicitly specify the filename (`import('./Apple.js')`). Is it possible to force nextjs to serve these dynamic modules?

Comment: It seems that you forgot to wrap your import with dynamic from "next/dynamic" module https://nextjs.org/docs#dynamic-import

Comment: @AndreiBelokopytov, I can't do it because the module I'm importing is not a React component

Answer (score 2):

You need to use the `dynamic` utility from `next/dynamic` for dynamic import in Next.js. This function is inspired by [react-loadable](https://github.com/jamiebuilds/react-loadable) library and uses similar syntax.

The simplest way to dynamically import React component in Next.js is:

```js
const DynamicComponent1 = dynamic(import('../components/hello1'))
```

If you want to import module that is not a React component than you need to use [customizing rendering](https://github.com/jamiebuilds/react-loadable#customizing-rendering) feature:

```js
const DynamicDeliveryOptions = dynamic({
  loader: () => import('../components/delivery-options'),
  render(props, loaded) {
    const options = loaded.deliveryOptions.map(
      option => <option key={option.id}>{option.title}</option>
    );
    return <select>{options}</select>
  },
});
```

Notice that signature of the `render` function in Next.js is different from 
its signature in react-loadable library (`props` is the first argument in Next.js).

Returning to your example: I think the best way to import multiple modules will be to declare them all as dynamic modules and conditionally render depending on the passed props (modules won't be loaded before render).

Answer (score 0):

You can tell webpack to put a dynamically named module inside a particular chunk using this syntax:

```js
const module = await import(
    /* webpackChunkName: "your_custom_chunk_name" */
    "path/to/your/module"
);
```

Webpack will extract your module's code inside the file: `/.next/server/chunks/your_custom_chunk_name.js`.

(Tested on NextJs version 12.1.6)